How to populate a list of matrices with values from a list of data frames with matching row/column names using a for loop?
I need to fill in a list of matrices with values from a list of pairwise comparison data frames. Data frame 1 will have the values for matrix 1 and data frame 2 for matrix 2 and so on. I attempted to create a loop for this but I get the same values in each matrix which is not what I want. I am not sure where my error lies and if this is the best approach to try to solve my problem.
Below I created a reproducible example of my problem.
I created three empty matrices with 0 as values
m <- matrix(0, 11, 11, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:11], LETTERS[1:11]))
m1 <- cbind(m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m)
m1 <- rbind(m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1,m1)
m2 <- m1
m3 <- m1

I create a list of these 3 matrices
host_matrix_l <- list(m1,m2,m3)
str(host_matrix_l)


I have a data frame with the values that I would like to fill each matrix with. To create a reproducible example I created these 3 data frames below
library("reshape2")

dimnames(m) <- list(Species1 = LETTERS[1:11], Species2 = LETTERS[1:11]) 
mydf_1 <- melt(m)[1:2]
head(mydf_1)
mydf_2 <- melt(m)[1:2]
mydf_3 <- melt(m)[1:2]


samples <- seq(from=0, to=0.5, by=.001)

set.seed(1)
mydf_1$distance <- sample(samples, size =121, replace =TRUE)
head(mydf_1)
tail(mydf_1)

set.seed(2)
mydf_2$distance <- sample(samples, size =121, replace =TRUE)
head(mydf_2)
tail(mydf_2)

set.seed(3)
mydf_3$distance <- sample(samples, size =121, replace =TRUE)
head(mydf_3)
tail(mydf_3)

I created a list of these three data frames
host_dist_df_l <- list(mydf_1, mydf_2, mydf_3)
str(host_dist_df_l)

now I want to populate each matrix in the list of matrices (that currently have 0) with the values of the data frames matching the row and column names of the matrix with the columns Species1 and Species2 of the data frames
for (m in 1:length(host_matrix_l)) {
    for (d in 1:length(host_dist_df_l))
        dist_df <- as.data.frame(host_dist_df_l[[d]]) 
            for (i in 1:nrow(dist_df)) {
                host_matrix_l[[m]][rownames(host_matrix_l[[m]]) == dist_df$Species2[i],
                colnames(host_matrix_l[[m]]) == dist_df$Species1[i]]<- dist_df$distance[i]
  }
}

head(host_matrix_l[[1]])
head(host_matrix_l[[2]])
head(host_matrix_l[[3]])

This is incorrect because we get the same values in all matrices. But matrix 1 should have the values from data frame 1 and matrix 2 should have the values of data frame 2 and so on. In my real life data, I have 100 matrices/data frames.
What is the error in my loop? Do you suggest a better way of solving this issue?

Possibly a lazy evaluation issue.  See section 6.5 of this page for more details.  Long story short: see if switching to lapply or one of its siblings helps.

The row and column names of your matrices are not unique which is going to cause you problems if you try to assign or subset by name. In the case of a wide matrix and long data frame, an easy way to assign from the data frame to the matrix would be something like m1[mydf_1$Species1, mydf_1$Species2] <- mydf_1$distance, but it won't work properly with duplicated row and column names.
